# Why is `/bin/ping` not found when in a Bash command-substitution subshell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ping

I've been trying to set up a bash loop which checks it can ping a remote address:

```
if $( /bin/ping -c 1 x.x.x.x ) ; then echo 'ok' ; fi
```

But I'm getting `PING: command not found`. I'm not really sure why this is happening.

The really weird thing is that if I do:

```
if $( /bin/ping  x.x.x.x ) ; then echo 'ok' ; fi
```

(i.e. without `-c 1`) then the shell blocks until I interrupt (because ping is in an infinite loop).

Can anyone explain what's going on?

(Yes, I could run it in the top-level shell and test `$?`, but why isn't this working the way I expect? This is in Bash on Ubuntu, if that changes anything.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the wrong expectations, as command substitution does not give you the $? exit status – it gives you the command's *stdout text*.

Keep in mind that bash's 'if' does not directly deal with strings or numbers. The condition between 'if..then' is always used as a command, and the branch depends on its exit status being zero vs non-zero. In other words, 'if' *by itself* is already nothing else than a $? check.

So if you want to replace a manual $? comparison, you can do that without any additional syntax features, like this:

```
if ping -c1 $addr; then echo ok; fi
```

But when you use command substitution – whether as an 'if' condition or as a standalone command – you're telling the shell to run the provided command's *stdout* as the real command. So because the usual output looks like this:

```
$ ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.39 ms
```

your command substitution results in something like the following expansion:

```
if PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.; then echo ok; fi
```

Hopefully obviously by now, this tells the shell to run the `PING` command with a ton of parameters as the actual 'if' condition.

(I used only the first line to keep the example brief, but in reality the whole multiline string is used – command substitution waits for the process to end. If the process runs infinitely, then $() will also keep collecting output forever and will never return.)

---

Side note 1: There is a *very similar* syntax, using just `( )` instead of `$( )`, that does a completely different thing. Some bash scripts written by C programmers might be doing this:

```
if ( ping -c 1 $addr ); then...
```

That's valid (although completely unnecessary) because it is not command substitution, but merely command grouping, and is otherwise identical to `if ping...;`.

Side note 2: There are valid cases for command substitution here, but usually it is not used alone – the most common use is with a string comparison operator, such as:

```
if [ "$(whoami)" = "root" ]; then echo ok; fi
```

Comment: And thanks for the level of detail in your answer, it's really appreciated.